# charCodeAt to return correct code for custom charcodes

Tags: javascript

Would this be good way to return correct code for custom charcodes

```
String.prototype._charCodeAt = String.prototype.charCodeAt;
String.prototype.charCodeAt = function( i , keycodes ) {
    if( keycodes !== 'undefined' ) {
        for( var j = 0; j < keycodes.length; j++ ) {
            if( this[i] === keycodes[j].char ) {
                return keycodes[j].code;
            }
        }
    } else {
        return this._charCodeAt( i );
    }
}
```

Keycodes is array where values stored like this

```
[
    ...
    { "char" : "ä" , "code" : 132 },
    { "char" : "à" , "code" : 133 },
    { "char" : "å" , "code" : 134 },
    ...
];
```

By default the javascript returns wrong values for the "special characters".
Is this code sufficient for this?

Comment: What do you mean it returns wrong values

Comment: For example
    
    "ä".charCodeAt(0)
    
Returns 228, and I should get 132 because the system I need to communicate with uses different character codes.

Comment: right, so different encoding than ucs-2 ? what encoding exactly?

Comment: I'm not sure if it is specific encoding but the stuff needs to be sent in as a bytearray and I'm just asking if my way is sufficient.

Comment: It seems to match with [IBM437](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IBM437) , please get more information about your requirements...

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use an object:

```
var codes = {
    "ä": 132,
    "à": 133,
    "å": 134
};

function customCharCodeAt( string, index ) {
    return codes[string.charAt(index)] || string.charCodeAt(index);
}
```

You should not override the normal `charCodeAt` function as it does return correct and expected
values.

Comment: Or you can extend `String.prototype` with something like `specialCharCodeAt`.